# What is the sign of chemical potential of a noninteracting classical ideal gas obeying MB distribution?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The chemical potential of a noninteracting Bose gas can never be negative while that of a noninteracting Fermi gas can be both positive or negative. What can be said about the chemical potential of noninteracting classical ideal gas obeying MB distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to compute this is through the grand canonical ensemble. The partition function for a single gas molecule is $Z_1 = V/\lambda^3$, where $\lambda$ is the thermal de Broglie wavelength. Then the grand partition function is
$$\mathcal{Z} = \sum_N e^{\beta \mu N} \frac{Z_1^N}{N!} = \exp\left( \frac{e^{\beta \mu} V}{\lambda^3}\right).$$
The particle number is found by differentiating,
$$N = \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial \log \mathcal{Z}}{\partial \mu} =\frac{e^{\beta \mu} V}{\lambda^3}.$$
Therefore, solving for $\mu$, we have
$$\mu = k_B T \log \frac{\lambda^3 N}{V}.$$
The ideal gas only behaves classically if the occupancy of each state is small, so we must have $\lambda^3 \ll V/N$. Then the logarithm is negative, so for a classical ideal gas $\mu < 0$.

Comment: +1 Could you provide some reference (book/paper) for the last equation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1420303 I'm not sure what you mean, a complete derivation of that equation is given right in this answer.

Comment: Complete and very clear! I was just looking a reference for citing the equation in a manuscript.

Comment: @user1420303 I think this particular equation is somewhere in Kardar's _Statistical Physics of Particles_.

Comment: @knzhou does that then mean it is favourable to put more particles in the system?